Threejs, Applying position.set() on a Group produces odd positions for its children
The initial position of the camera is (0,0,0). I set this because I want to display a flat object on a flat surface like Pigma. Next, create a new room in your new room. To create a room, we receive four vertex coordinates called points as this.getShadowPoints() function and use createRoom. make a room Find the center of the four vertex coordinates and change that position to this.position.set() as the center point. We will also create a floor using a class called D2Floor. The D2Floor class generates a geometry that connects four coordinates. Also, this is an add() to the Room class. I confirmed that the point coordinates of the Room class, D2Floor, and Shape class are the same. However, the actual location is completely different. If you do not change the position to this.position.set(center) in the Room class, a D2Floor will be generated correctly at the set position, but if you change the position, it will be generated at an abnormal position.
Here is the code:
// Room class
export class D2Room extends THREE.Group {
  lines = null;
  clickedPoints = null;

  constructor({ points }) {
    super();
    this.name = "shadow";
    this.clickedPoints = points[0];
    this.drawLines(points);
    this.userData = {};
  }

  getShadowPoints = () => {
    const shadow = this.getObjectByName("shadowLines");
    const points = [];
    const positions = shadow.geometry.attributes.position.array;
    for (let i = 0; i < positions.length; i += 3) {
      points.push(
        new THREE.Vector3(positions[i], positions[i + 1], positions[i + 2])
      );
    }
    points.pop();
    return points;
  };

  createRoom = ({ cameraZoom }) => {
    if (this.getObjectByName("floor")) {
      this.remove(this.getObjectByName("floor"));
    }
    const box = new THREE.Box3();
    box.setFromCenterAndSize(
      new THREE.Vector3(1, 1, 1),
      new THREE.Vector3(2, 1, 3)
    );
    
    //set box on center
    const helper = new THREE.Box3Helper(box, 0xffff00);
    this.add(helper);
    const points = this.getShadowPoints();
    console.log("createRoom points = ", points);

    const center = calculateCenter(points);
    this.position.set(center.x, center.y, center.z);
    const floor = new D2Floor({ points });
    this.userData = {
      ...this.userData,
      points,
    };
    if (!this.getObjectByName("circleGroup")) {
      this.createDots();
    }
    this.add(floor);
    const rotationController = new RotationController({ cameraZoom });
    rotationController.visible = false;
    rotationController.position.set(0, 10, 0);
    this.add(rotationController);
  };
// ... and more codes
}



//D2Floor and Shape class
export class D2Floor {
  constructor({ points, height }) {
    console.log("floor points = ", points);
    const shape = new Shape({ points });
    const geometry = new THREE.ShapeGeometry(shape);
    let material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
      side: height ? THREE.BackSide : THREE.FrontSide,
    });
    const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    mesh.name = "floor";
    mesh.renderOrder = 1;
    mesh.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2;

    if (height) {
      mesh.position.y = height;
    }

    return mesh;
  }
}

export class Shape extends THREE.Shape {
  constructor({ points }) {
    const shape = super();
    shape.moveTo(points[0].x, -points[0].z);
    for (let i = 1; i < points.length; i++) {
      shape.lineTo(points[i].x, -points[i].z);
    }
    shape.lineTo(points[0].x, -points[0].z); 

    return shape;
  }
}


The plane with the yellow box is the plane where I want it to be, and the plane with the red frame is the plane that was actually created. Also, these are the actual point coordinates I set.
I found that if I get the center coordinate from a point in D2Floor and move it just back to the x, z axis of that center coordinate, the plane is located where I originally intended it to be.
export class D2Floor {
  constructor({ points, height }) {
    const shape = new Shape({ points });
    const geometry = new THREE.ShapeGeometry(shape);
    let material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
      side: height ? THREE.BackSide : THREE.FrontSide,
    });
    const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    const center = calculateCenter(points);
    mesh.position.set(-center.x, center.y, -center.z); //add !!
    mesh.name = "floor";
    mesh.renderOrder = 1;
    mesh.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2;

    if (height) {
      mesh.position.y = height;
    }

    return mesh;
  }
}

But I need to apply it to all children in Room.
